# How can I draw text with different stroke and fill colors on images with python?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

How can I draw text with different stroke and fill colors on images with python?

Here is some text with red stroke and gray fill.

[image: Example]

I tried to do this with PIL but there was no option for setting the stroke color.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using [cairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/) (with much code taken from [here](http://cairographics.org/samples/text/)):

```
import cairo

def text_extent(font, font_size, text, *args, **kwargs):
    surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, 0, 0)
    ctx = cairo.Context(surface)
    ctx.select_font_face(font, *args, **kwargs)
    ctx.set_font_size(font_size)
    return ctx.text_extents(text)

text='Example'
font="Sans"
font_size=55.0
font_args=[cairo.FONT_SLANT_NORMAL]
(x_bearing, y_bearing, text_width, text_height,
 x_advance, y_advance) = text_extent(font, font_size, text, *font_args)
surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, int(text_width), int(text_height))
ctx = cairo.Context(surface)
ctx.select_font_face(font, *font_args)
ctx.set_font_size(font_size)
ctx.move_to(-x_bearing, -y_bearing)
ctx.text_path(text)
ctx.set_source_rgb(0.47, 0.47, 0.47)
ctx.fill_preserve()
ctx.set_source_rgb(1, 0, 0)
ctx.set_line_width(1.5)
ctx.stroke()

surface.write_to_png("/tmp/out.png")
```

[image]

Comment: Do I need to know the dimensions of the text to use this?

Comment: I can get the needed info with Context.text_extents("Example") but after that I need to create a new surface with the correct width and height.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I do not know a better way.

Comment: @unutbu, i ported your code into C++ successfully, but having an issue reg transparency. can you check it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43299640/cairo-fill-with-transparency) Thanks

Answer (score 9):

PIL doesn't support this but you can fake it: Render the text four or eight times with the outline color using one pixel offsets:

```
x+1,y
x-1,y
x  ,y+1
x  ,y-1
```

(four times version)

```
x+1,y+1
x  ,y+1
x-1,y+1

x+1,y
x-1,y

x+1,y-1
x  ,y-1 
x-1,y-1
```

(eight times version)

and then once at `x,y` with the fill color.

Comment: The 8x version is basically equivalent to rendering 4 times on only the diagonals.

Comment: @HassanBaig You won't notice it.

Comment: It only works if the border is thin, for example, 1 pixel. If you use a wider border, the produced text is not so satisfactory.

Answer (score 7):

Using [imagemagick](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=imagemagick&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://www.imagemagick.org/&ei=NSK5TvOKC6q22gX02cTVBw&usg=AFQjCNEj86ZXrN6Iqx9rZ73Ad4L4ypmDtQ):

```
import subprocess

args = {
    'bgColor': 'transparent',
    'fgColor': 'light slate grey',
    'fgOutlineColor': 'red',
    'text': 'Example',
    'size': 72,
    'geometry': '350x100!',
    'output': '/tmp/out.png',
    'font': 'helvetica'
}

cmd = ['convert', 'xc:{bgColor}', '-resize', '{geometry}', '-gravity', 'Center', 
       '-font', '{font}', '-pointsize', '{size}', '-fill', '{fgColor}', 
       '-stroke', '{fgOutlineColor}', '-draw', "text 0,0 '{text}'", '-trim', '{output}']
cmd = [item.format(**args) for item in cmd]

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
proc.communicate()
```

[image]

Comment: Do I need to know the dimensions of the output text before I can create it?

Comment: You may use any `geometry` you wish -- imagemagick will create an image of exactly that geometry as long as you use the exclamation point -- but if the font `size` is too large, part of the text may be cropped off.

Comment: I would like to get a picture that is the exact size of the text. No cropped text and no extra space on some side.

Comment: You can crop to the size of the text using the `-trim` option.

Comment: It would be better to put the command and it's options into a list and then replace variables in each element. That would solve the problem of spaces and/or quote characters in arguments.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: Thanks for the suggestion/improvement.

Answer (score 6):

They added a native solution within Pillow since 6.2.0: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text

You now specify the `stroke_fill` which is the color of the outline and `stroke_width` which is the thickness of the outline.

Comment: To update pillow, `pip install -U pillow`. This works for Pillow 7.2.

Comment: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text link to the specific heading.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Inkscape:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("inkscape in.svg --export-text-to-path --export-plain-svg out.svg", shell = True)
```

note: you have to download Inkscape to use this, so not practical for permanent use

Answer (score 2):

Complementing @Aaron Digulla's answer, this is how you fake the outline color in PIL:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def main():
    text_color = (255, 0, 0)
    outline_color = (0, 0, 255)
    size = (512, 256)
    img = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=size, color=(255, 255, 255))
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font="C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/STKAITI.TTF", size=100)
    drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    x = 10
    y = 10
    bd_w = 1
    drawer.text((x-bd_w, y), "测试文字", font=font, fill=outline_color)
    drawer.text((x, y-bd_w), "测试文字", font=font, fill=outline_color)
    drawer.text((x+bd_w, y), "测试文字", font=font, fill=outline_color)
    drawer.text((x, y+bd_w), "测试文字", font=font, fill=outline_color)

    drawer.text((x+bd_w, y-bd_w), "测试文字", font=font, fill=outline_color)
    drawer.text((x-bd_w, y-bd_w), "测试文字", font=font, fill=outline_color)
    drawer.text((x-bd_w, y+bd_w), "测试文字", font=font, fill=outline_color)
    drawer.text((x+bd_w, y+bd_w), "测试文字", font=font, fill=outline_color)

    drawer.text((x, y), "测试文字", font=font, fill=text_color)

    img.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But be warned that this method will produce unsatisfactory text if `bd_w` (border width) is set a little higher. See the following image for effect of `bd_w`:

border width = 1

[image]

border width = 4

[image]

border width = 7

[image]

It seems that for large text keeping border width below 4 is acceptable.