# Create a halo around text in Python using PIL?

Tags: python, text, python-imaging-library

I'm watermarking some pictures using PIL and I'm having a hard time reading some of the text (black text on dark background).  I can't just change text color since I've got a wide array of background colors.  Is there any way to add a halo effect around the text?

For example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhRe1.jpg
The bottom text is what I've got, and the top text is what I'm hoping to get (colors aside).  I really just need a thin outline around the text.  Any ideas?  I can upload some code if you really think it'll make a difference, but it's just a normal PIL ImageDraw.Draw command.  Thanks!

Comment: Print the text three times. The first two with the outline color and offsets of (-1, -1) and (1, 1) and the third with the original color at the original position.

Comment: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2009-May/005681.html

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8050556/442650

Comment: PIL.ImageDraw has an `outline` option but it isn't valid for text.

Comment: @MarkRansom: what a helpfully unhelpful factoid!

Comment: @HassanBaig sometimes it's worth knowing what *not* to try so you don't waste time on it.

Comment: @MarkRansom: true that; that's why the unhelpful factoid is *helpful*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to outline text with a dark line in PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556771/is-there-a-way-to-outline-text-with-a-dark-line-in-pil)

Answer (score 14):

If you don't care about speed too much, you can do it using composition:

1. draw text with halo color on a blank `RGBA` image
2. blur it
3. draw it again with text color
4. invert this image to get composition mask
5. "merge" with original image

For example:

```
import sys
import Image, ImageChops, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageFilter

def draw_text_with_halo(img, position, text, font, col, halo_col):
    halo = Image.new('RGBA', img.size, (0, 0, 0, 0))
    ImageDraw.Draw(halo).text(position, text, font = font, fill = halo_col)
    blurred_halo = halo.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
    ImageDraw.Draw(blurred_halo).text(position, text, font = font, fill = col)
    return Image.composite(img, blurred_halo, ImageChops.invert(blurred_halo))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
    font = ImageFont.load_default()
    txt = 'Example 1234'
    text_col = (0, 255, 0) # bright green
    halo_col = (0, 0, 0)   # black
    i2 = draw_text_with_halo(i, (20, 20), txt, font, text_col, halo_col)
    i2.save('halo.png')
```

It has many advantages:

- the result is smooth and looks nice
- you can choose different filter instead of `BLUR` to get different "halo"
- it works even with very large fonts and still looks great

To get thicker halo, you may use filter like this:

```
kernel = [
    0, 1, 2, 1, 0,
    1, 2, 4, 2, 1,
    2, 4, 8, 4, 1,
    1, 2, 4, 2, 1,
    0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
kernelsum = sum(kernel)
myfilter = ImageFilter.Kernel((5, 5), kernel, scale = 0.1 * sum(kernel))
blurred_halo = halo.filter(myfilter)
```

The part `scale = 0.1 * sum(kernel)` makes the halo thicker (small values) or dimmer (big values).

Comment: I think a proper outline would look better in this case, as in the example in the question, but this is the correct way to generate a "halo". The only downside is that the wider you make the halo the dimmer it gets. I'm a bit disappointed that PIL doesn't give a more straight-forward way of blending an RGBA image over another.

Comment: Cool thanks. Just one question... the blur is very blurred out... with black text and white blur... the blur does in fact turn out invisible on a black background. How can we sharpen this? Maybe that is what you mean by thicker halo?

Comment: @Jonny yes, that would probably be it. Or, you can use different filter (see: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageFilter.html), play with *scale* or *offset* values in http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageFilter.html#PIL.ImageFilter.Kernel