# Is there a way to outline text with a dark line in PIL?

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm using python/PIL to write text on a set of `PNG` images. I was able to get the font I wanted, but I'd like to now outline the text in black.

**This is what I have:** as you can see, if the background is white it is difficult to read.

[image]

**This is the goal:**

[image]

Is there a way to accomplish this with PIL? If not, I am open to hearing other suggestions, but no promises because I've already begun a large project in python using PIL.

**The section of code that deals with drawing on the images:**

```
for i in range(0,max_frame_int + 1):
    writeimg = Image.open("frameinstance" + str(i) + ".png")
    newimg = Image.new("RGB", writeimg.size)
    newimg.paste(writeimg)
    width_image = newimg.size[0]
    height_image = newimg.size[1]
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(newimg)
    # font = ImageFont.truetype(<font-file>, <font-size>)
    for font_size in range(50, 0, -1):
        font = ImageFont.truetype("impact.ttf", font_size)
        if font.getsize(meme_text)[0] <= width_image:
            break
    else:
        print('no fonts fit!')

    # draw.text((x, y),"Sample Text",(r,g,b))
    draw.text((int(0.05*width_image), int(0.7*height_image)),meme_text,(255,255,255),font=font)
    newimg.save("newimg" + str(i) +".png")
```

Comment: 'if the background is white, it is difficult to read'. Probably not intended but with that photo, that phrase was hilarious!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I draw text with different stroke and fill colors on images with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049764/how-can-i-draw-text-with-different-stroke-and-fill-colors-on-images-with-python)

Comment: Looks like `Pillow` added an option to outline text about a year ago. [This is a solution which shows you how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62868186/6331353)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outline text on image in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62737084/outline-text-on-image-in-python)

Answer (score 23):

You can take a look at this [Text Outline Using PIL](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2009-May/005681.html):

```
from PIL import ImageDraw, ImageFont, Image

import win32api, os

x, y = 10, 10

fname1 = "c:/test.jpg"
im = Image.open(fname1)
pointsize = 30
fillcolor = "red"
shadowcolor = "yellow"

text = "hi there"

font = win32api.GetWindowsDirectory() + "\\Fonts\\ARIALBD.TTF"
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
font = ImageFont.truetype(font, pointsize)

# thin border
draw.text((x-1, y), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((x+1, y), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((x, y-1), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((x, y+1), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)

# thicker border
draw.text((x-1, y-1), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((x+1, y-1), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((x-1, y+1), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((x+1, y+1), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)

# now draw the text over it
draw.text((x, y), text, font=font, fill=fillcolor)

fname2 = "c:/test2.jpg"
im.save(fname2)

os.startfile(fname2)
```

Comment: To give links alone you can use the comments section. In case you have an answer or a point to prove only then use the answer section.

Comment: It is a helpful link by the way :)

Comment: Sure Thanks will do.

Comment: This solution has issues that become apparent at higher pixel sizes.  Instead it would be better to use the built in `stroke_width` and `stroke_fill` parameters supported by ImageDraw.text: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text

Answer (score 20):

Check the [stroke_width](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/52c66bbcfb35fa8bf808fab3d61fb100fd24110a/src/PIL/ImageDraw.py#L277) option, which implements `stroke/border/outline` effect. For `shadow` effect, you can draw with a small offset. Bellow is an example to add subtitle to image.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont


def add_subtitle(
    bg,
    text="nice",
    xy=("center", 20),
    font="font/SourceHanSansSC-Regular.otf",
    font_size=53,
    font_color=(255, 255, 255),
    stroke=2,
    stroke_color=(0, 0, 0),
    shadow=(4, 4),
    shadow_color=(0, 0, 0),
):
    """draw subtitle on image by pillow
    Args:
        bg(PIL image): image to add subtitle
        text(str): subtitle
        xy(tuple): absolute top left location of subtitle
        ...: extra style of subtitle
    Returns:
        bg(PIL image): image with subtitle
    """
    stroke_width = stroke
    xy = list(xy)
    W, H = bg.width, bg.height
    font = ImageFont.truetype(str(font), font_size)
    w, h = font.getsize(text, stroke_width=stroke_width)
    if xy[0] == "center":
        xy[0] = (W - w) // 2
    if xy[1] == "center":
        xy[1] = (H - h) // 2
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(bg)
    if shadow:
        draw.text(
            (xy[0] + shadow[0], xy[1] + shadow[1]), text, font=font, fill=shadow_color
        )
    draw.text(
        (xy[0], xy[1]),
        text,
        font=font,
        fill=font_color,
        stroke_width=stroke_width,
        stroke_fill=stroke_color,
    )
    return bg


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bg = Image.open("./Screenshot_20200626-131218.png")
    bg = add_subtitle(bg)
    bg.save("out.png")
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer. Does exactly what the OP wanted with no additional code (the stroke_width and stroke_fill parameters make all the difference).

Answer (score 13):

PIL now supports this feature.  The below code works in 9.2.0

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

caption = 'I need to update my Pillow'
img = Image.open('./example-img.jpg')
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype('impact.ttf', size=50)
d.text((10, 400), caption, fill='white', font=font,
       stroke_width=2, stroke_fill='black')
img.save('example-output.jpg')
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

This is how I handled the problem when I needed to do it for frame counters. Just a heads up if you start to push this too far for the thickness, then you will need more draws to cover your areas you're missing.

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw,ImageFont
import os

#setting varibles
imgFile = "frame_0.jpg"
output = "frame_edit_0.jpg"
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 30)
text = "SEQ_00100_SHOT_0004_FR_0001"
textColor = 'white'
shadowColor = 'black'
outlineAmount = 3

#open image
img = Image.open(imgFile)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

#get the size of the image
imgWidth,imgHeight = img.size

#get text size
txtWidth, txtHeight = draw.textsize(text, font=font)

#get location to place text
x = imgWidth - txtWidth - 100
y = imgHeight - txtHeight - 100

#create outline text
for adj in range(outlineAmount):
    #move right
    draw.text((x-adj, y), text, font=font, fill=shadowColor)
    #move left
    draw.text((x+adj, y), text, font=font, fill=shadowColor)
    #move up
    draw.text((x, y+adj), text, font=font, fill=shadowColor)
    #move down
    draw.text((x, y-adj), text, font=font, fill=shadowColor)
    #diagnal left up
    draw.text((x-adj, y+adj), text, font=font, fill=shadowColor)
    #diagnal right up
    draw.text((x+adj, y+adj), text, font=font, fill=shadowColor)
    #diagnal left down
    draw.text((x-adj, y-adj), text, font=font, fill=shadowColor)
    #diagnal right down
    draw.text((x+adj, y-adj), text, font=font, fill=shadowColor)

#create normal text on image
draw.text((x,y), text, font=font, fill=textColor)

img.save(output)
print 'Finished'
os.startfile(output)
```

Comment: This worked for me. I used a loop for the inner part to make the code shorter:```
    dxy = [(dx,dy) for dx in [-1,0,1] for dy in [-1,0,1]]
    for i in range(1, 1+outline):
        for dx,dy in dxy:
            draw.text((x+dx*i, y+dy*i), **kwshadow)```

Answer (score 1):

```
import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

import win32api, os

x, y = 10, 10

fname1 = "c:/test.jpg"
im = Image.open(fname1)
pointsize = 30
fillcolor = "red"
shadowcolor = "yellow"

text = "hi there"

font = win32api.GetWindowsDirectory() + "\\Fonts\\ARIALBD.TTF"
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
font = ImageFont.truetype(font, pointsize)

# thin border
draw.text((x-1, y), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((x+1, y), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((x, y-1), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((x, y+1), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)

# thicker border
draw.text((x-1, y-1), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((x+1, y-1), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((x-1, y+1), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((x+1, y+1), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)

# now draw the text over it
draw.text((x, y), text, font=font, fill=fillcolor)

fname2 = "c:/test2.jpg"
im.save(fname2)

os.startfile(fname2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for that on the internet and I saw that PIL doesn't have native support to add text border. In that case, I create this proposal method based on [Alec Bennett solution](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2009-May/005681.html).

The problem that I found with that solution is about how to create a smooth border on larger border size.
 [Problem Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0uTG.jpg)

If we walk over 360 degrees or 2pi radians, adding the same text, we could create a better implementation of the text border functionality.

Here's the example function

```
    def add_text(image, text, location, font, fontsize=14, fontcolor=(0, 0, 0), 
                 border=0, border_color=(0, 0, 0), points=15):
        font_format = ImageFont.truetype(font, fontsize)
        drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

        if border:
            (x, y) = location
            for step in range(0, math.floor(border * points), 1):
                angle = step * 2 * math.pi / math.floor(border * points)
                drawer.text((x - border * math.cos(angle), y - border * math.sin(angle)), text, border_color, font=font_format)
        drawer.text(location, text, fontcolor, font=font_format)
        return image
```

The same image, text and config generate the next [Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Vyj.jpg)