# How do I add white text with a black drop shadow to any image?

Tags: image, go, fonts, png, jpeg

I'm using `github.com/fogleman/gg` to draw some white text on an image:

```
existing, _ := gg.LoadJPG(path)
dc := gg.NewContextForImage(existing)
dc.SetRGB(0, 0, 0)
dc.DrawString(word, x, y)
dc.SetRGB(1, 1, 1)
dc.DrawString(word, x-3, y-3)
```

And sometimes it looks perfect:

[image]

But sometimes it's terrible:

[image]

Is there a trick to make it readable on any image?

Comment: There are some good ideas here https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#anno_on

Answer (score 0):

Oh I think I see what to do:

https://www.tiktok.com/@virtual.tails/video/7256528174178127147?_r=1&_t=8eoEPjc11oJ

[image]

You have to really make a huge black background for each letter not just a tiny drop shadow.

```
  for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    angle := float64(i) / float64(smoothness) * 2 * math.Pi
    xOffset := math.Cos(angle) * 4
    yOffset := math.Sin(angle) * 4
    dc.DrawStringAnchored(letter, x+xOffset, y+yOffset, 0.5, 0.5)
  }
```

Update: it's easier to just do this in python:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62941753/148736

```
pip3 install pillow
```

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageFilter, ImageChops
import sys
import random

filename = sys.argv[1]
x = int(sys.argv[2])
y = int(sys.argv[3])
text = sys.argv[4]
result = sys.argv[5]

image = Image.open(filename)
bg = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

font = ImageFont.truetype('font.ttf',96)

colors = ['white', 'pink', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'yellow', 'purple', 'cyan']

fill_color = random.choice(colors)

ranX = random.randint(-10, 10)
ranY = random.randint(-10, 10)

bg.text((x + ranX, y + ranY), text, fill=fill_color, font=font, spacing = 4, align = 'center', stroke_width=8, stroke_fill='black')
image.save(result)
```