# Cairo Fill with Transparency

Tags: c++, image, drawing, cairo, alpha-transparency

I'm new to Cairo, trying to create text with transparent color and stroke. 
stroke color's transparency works but text fill color transparency `transparency_value`  doesn't work.
If i reduce `transparency_value` , text color just gets darker(black) and increasing `transparency_value` makes text color brighter (green in my case)

```
 cairo_surface_t* surface = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 640, 480);
 cairo_t* cairo = cairo_create(surface);
 cairo_set_font_face(cairo, myfont_face);
 cairo_set_font_size(cairo, 25);
 cairo_text_extents_t extents;  
 cairo_text_extents(cairo, "Hello World", &extents);
 cairo_move_to(cairo, 200, 200);        
 cairo_text_path(cairo, "Hello World"); 
 double transparency_value = 0.5;
 cairo_set_source_rgba(cairo, 0,1,0,transparency_value ); //transparency doesn't work
 //cairo_fill(cairo);  //this didn't make a difference
 cairo_fill_preserve(cairo);
 cairo_set_source_rgba(cairo, 0.56, 0.76, 0.96, 0.5); //transparency works
 cairo_set_line_width(cairo, 1.5);
 cairo_stroke(cairo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you are drawing your text outside of the surface? In the following example I added a call to `cairo_move_to(cr, 200, 200)` and now I get the following result. (This is written in Lua and uses https://github.com/pavouk/lgi to call into cairo; comments indicate things that I changed compared to your version)

```
local cairo = require("lgi").cairo
local surface = cairo.ImageSurface.create(cairo.Format.ARGB32, 640, 480)
local cr = cairo.Context(surface)
local myfont_face = cr:get_font_face() -- I have to get this from somewhere
cr:move_to(200, 200) -- I added this line to make something appear
cr:set_font_face(myfont_face)
cr:set_font_size(25)
cr:text_path("Hello World")
local transparency_value = 0.5
cr:set_source_rgba(0, 1, 0, transparency_value)
-- cr:fill()
cr:fill_preserve()
cr:set_source_rgba(0.65, 0.76, 0.96, 0.5)
cr:set_line_width(5) -- changed from 1.5 to 5 to make it more prominent
cr:stroke()
surface:write_to_png("/tmp/out.png")
```

[image]

Edit: And this is the result when I change `transparency_value` to 0.1. Clearly, the result is different and transparency works correctly (when zooming in, you still see some faint green in the middle).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had used `cairo_move_to`, or else i wouldn't see output. to make code short i had skipped `cairo_move_to`.I have updated code.  am i doing any mistake in the order of function calls? 
and did you try changing `transparency_value` in your code?

Comment: See my edit. I added another image showing the result with `transparency_value = 0.1`. The result still looks as expected and I cannot reproduce the black that you are seeing. What am I doing "wrong"?

Comment: hmm! is this a bug in C++  or is it possible that i didn't build cairo with freeType library properly - so getting wrong output?

Comment: A bug in C++? As in, the ISO standard? Why? And Freetype is not involved in the transparency here. So, what are you seeing on your end exactly? Can you produce a minimal reproducing example that I could run here?